# Replace Beans.xml configuration in Spring

Tags: spring, javabeans

How can I replace beans.xml file for testing purposes?
I use

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:Beans.xml")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

to init class, but in my testing class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ArrayCointainerTest {
```

I'd like to use another one.
Any idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a separate configuration class which has you beans xml imported and annotate that with @TestConfiguration. Spring boot automatically pick this up as your test configuration

[Detecting test configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)